# Should I write a new vertex shader for objects that doesn't use the MVP matrix?

Tags: opengl

I have been writing a 2d renderer using OpenGL with camera controls, but there are some objects that should not have a camera applied to it because they are used to draw things like buttons, health bars, etc
that will stay on your screen no matter where your camera is. Should I write a separate vertex shader for those objects or should I use the same vertex shader?

If I use the same vertex shader, should I do something like this

```
#version 330 core
layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;

uniform int haveCameraAppliedTo;
uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 model;

void main()
{
     if(haveCameraAppliedTo == 0)
     {
          gl_Position = position;
     }
     if(haveCameraAppliedTo == 1)
     {
          gl_Position = projection * view * model * position;
     }
}
```

or are their different ways to handling this problem?

Comment: Cant you just pass the shader an identity matrix? Also, you really don't want to use (ideally any) if statements in shaders, these are very slow

Comment: I was planning on using batch rendering so I can't really modify the uniform variables in between different quads being drawn, but thank you for mentioning that if statements are slow in shaders because I was also wondering why my last project was running really slow(it have like 4 if statements in the vertex and fragment shaders).

Comment: You can change the uniforms between drawcalls (and with batchrendering, theres still drawcalls for each texture, just the quads are batched), but in that case it might be easier to just use another shader instead of changing the uniform back and forth

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think I can do `gl_Position = (projection * view * model * haveCameraAppliedTo * position) + (position * (1 - haveCameraAppliedTo));`. If the variable haveCameraAppliedTo is 0, it cancels out `(projection * view * model * haveCameraAppliedTo * position)` part of the equation and leaves out just the positions and if the haveCameraAppliedTo variable is 1, it leaves in the MVP matrices and cancels out the `(position * (1 - haveCameraAppliedTo))` part of the equation. If this is inefficient or slow, please let me know. Thank you.